# Downloaded MVC application is not loaded in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am newbie in .NET Development.
I just downloaded a built application and using the following products:

MVC 4 framework 
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit

But when I try to run .sln(solution file) file I get the following error:

C:\Users...\Desktop\contosouniversity\contosouniversity\contosouniversity.csproj : error : The project file 'C:\Users...\Desktop\contosouniversity\contosouniversity\contosouniversity.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.

I am using MVC4 framework for loading this project, Visual studio 2010 MVC4 framework seems to be working with lower versions i guess(i.e. MVC3) , if i am doing wrong, please let me know.

Is it necessary to download MVC3 as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to install MVC3 and tools. Install them using `Microsoft Web Platform`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you upgrade MVC using Web Tools Plataform or download [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAndWebTools20122ReleaseCandidate.aspx).